# WebFlux is unable to decode Chunked requests properly

Tags: spring-webflux, netty, chunked

I used Webflux+netty as my web server;

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now ,the client request with chunked body :

```
20000;chunk-signature=e80ce782d5fb75f82f7b43d680ea7146dd9d7b4d314b51c38b2e60aec9888522
myobjects1
myobjects10
myobjects100
myobjects10009
myobjects10010
....
```

My controller is as follows:

```
request.getBody()
                    .map(dataBuffer -> {
....
            dataBuffer.toByteBuffer(toBuf);
......
```

Then toBuf of content still include "20000;chunk-signature=e80ce78...." ，And I can^t fetch the real body without "20000;chunk-***" ;
Has anyone  encountered this issue?  And to ensure proper decoding of Chunked Requests in Webflux;

I find spring issue ALL， No matching issue found